# How to do client-side UI events in Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor, javascript-interop

I just started playing around with Blazor and I can already see the great potential of this new framework.

I'm wondering, though, how it will handle doing simple things like setting focus on an input control? For instance, after I handle a click event, I want to set the focus to a text input control. Do I have to use JQuery for something like that, or will Blazor have some built-in methods for that sort of thing?

Thanks

**Update: I posted an answer below with an example of how to set the focus to a control by invoking a JavaScript function from the .Net code.**

As of right now (Blazor 0.9.0) you create your JavaScript functions in the Index.html (or reference them from Index.html) and then in your Blazor page or component you call JsRuntime.InvokeAsync("functionName", parms);

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-components/javascript-interop

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I want to add a more up-to-date (as of 0.9.0) example of calling a JavaScript function to set the focus to another control after some event, like clicking on a button. This might be helpful for someone just starting out with Blazor (like me).

This example builds on the example code in the Blazor documentation "Build Your First Blazor Components App" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-your-first-razor-components-app?view=aspnetcore-3.0

First, follow all the instructions in the documentation. When you have a working To-Do List page, then add the following:

1. At the bottom of Index.html, under wwwroot, and below the script tag that loads the webassembly.js, add the following script:

```
<script>
        window.MySetFocus = (ctrl) => {
            document.getElementById(ctrl).focus();
            return true;
        }
</script>
```

2. At the top of your todo.cshtml page, add the following using statement:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime;
```

3. In the @functions section of your todo.cshtml page, add the following function:

```
    async void Focus(string controlId)
    {
        var obj = JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>(
            "MySetFocus", controlId);
    }
```

4. In the AddToDo() function, just below the line where you set the "newToDo" variable to an empty string, add a call to the Focus function, passing in the string id of the input control. (The example in the docs does not assign an ID to the input control, so just add one yourself. I named mine "todoItem").

```
void AddTodo()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
        {
            todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo });
            newTodo = string.Empty;
            Focus("todoItem"); // this is the new code
        }
    }
```

5. Build and run your app. When you click the add new item button, the new item should be added to the list, the input control blanked out, and the focus should be back in the input control, ready for another item to be added.

Comment: For those who created from VSCode template, there is no index.html. Use _Host.cshtml instead.

Answer (score 15):

Blazor is just the replacement (to be more precise "value addition") to JavaScript. It is a client-side only solution (but it might add some easy binding to ASP.NET in the future).

Still, it's completely based on HTML and CSS. C# is replacing the JS part using web assembly. So nothing has changed on how you access / modify HTML controls.

As of now (version 0.1.0) you have to rely on HTML DOM `focus()` Method to do what you intend to do (yes you have to use **JavaScript** as of now :( ).

```
// Not tested code
// This is JavaScript. 
// Put this inside the index.html. Just below <script type="blazor-boot"></script>
<script>
    Blazor.registerFunction('Focus', (controlId) => {
      return document.getElementById(controlId).focus();
    });
</script>

//and then wrap it for calls from .NET:    
// This is C#

public static object Focus(string controlId)
{
    return RegisteredFunction.Invoke<object>("Focus", controlId);
    //object type is used since Invoke does not have a overload for void methods. Don't know why. 
    //this will return undefined according to js specs
}
```

For more information, you can refer to below.

**If you want to improve the packaging of JS neatly**, you can do something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49521216/476609

```
public class BlazorExtensionScripts : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Components.BlazorComponent
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.RenderTree.RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "script");
        builder.AddContent(1, "Blazor.registerFunction('Focus', (controlId) => { document.getElementById(controlId).focus(); });");
        builder.CloseElement();
    }

    public static void Focus(string controlId)
    {
        RegisteredFunction.Invoke<object>("Focus", controlId);
    }
}
```

then add this component to the root: (`App.cshtml`):

```
<BlazorExtensionScripts></BlazorExtensionScripts>
<Router AppAssembly=typeof(Program).Assembly />
```

Comment: This answer is now obsolete. Please see the update above, or go to the documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-components/javascript-interop

Comment: If I can't access and control the DOM directly from C# then what's the point? Using this approach I'll end up with a client that's part C# and part Javascript, which is even worst than a client that's all Javascript.

Comment: @Neutrino Unfortunately this is a problem with WebAssembly in general and not blazor. WebAssembly currently can not access the DOM. It's been discussed to add to the roadmap, but I don't know what the current status of it is.

Many would argue that in most cases you don't actually *need* to access the DOM, but that's an entirely separate discussion.

Answer (score 4):

From .NET 5 Preview 8

[Set UI focus in Blazor apps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-preview-8/#set-ui-focus-in-blazor-apps)

Blazor now has a FocusAsync convenience method on ElementReference for setting the UI focus on that element.

```
<button @onclick="() => textInput.FocusAsync()">Set focus</button>
<input @ref="textInput"/>
```

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer.

Comment: `<span class="menu-arrow" @onclick="(e) => e.stopPropagation()"></span>`
This is what I want to do but it gives me error. `error CS1061: 'MouseEventArgs' does not contain a defini 
tion for 'stopPropagation' and no accessible extension method 'stopPropagation' accepting a first argument of type 'MouseEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly re 
ference?`

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly call JavaScript function. You are required to first register your functions like,

```
<script>
 Blazor.registerFunction('ShowControl', (item) => {       
     var txtInput = document.getElementById("txtValue");         
     txtInput.style.display = "";
     txtInput.value = item;
     txtInput.focus();          
});
return true;
</script>
```

Then you need to declare a method in C# which calls this JavaScript function. Like,

```
private void CallJavaScript()
{
   RegisteredFunction.Invoke<bool>("ShowControl", itemName);
}
```

You can call this C# method on click of button. Like,

```
<button id="btnShow" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick(CallJavaScript)>Show</button>
```

This post [Create a CRUD App using Blazor and ASP.NET Core](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/create-a-crud-app-using-blazor-and-asp-net-core/)
shows a working demo of calling JavaScript from Blazor.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the referenced article this morning. Appreciate your input.

Comment: This method is now out of date. Please the update in the question area above, or see the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-components/javascript-interop